# How to to get objects from the model with multiple filters?

Tags: python, django

I'm having a little problem with retrieving data from the models. On my HTML i have a form in which i get multiple filters for the data, for example: I have quality and presentation variables, the user choose how he wants to filter, and i send a query in the format 'key1=value1&key2=value2' and things like that. My problem is that, in the views, i don't know how to use this to filter the data.

I have this little code to give format to the query

```
filt = {'quality':[],'presentation':[], 'color':[]}
quer1 = request.POST.get('value');
print quer1
quer = quer1.split('&')
for i in quer:
    val = i.split('=')
    filt[val[0]].append(val[1])
```

With this i create a dict with the data to filter, but then, How can i make a get with the variables of the dict?

I mean something like

```
Products.objects.get(filt)
```

Where filt would be a variable in which i only left the non empty lists.

I know that if i made it manually, would be something like

```
Products.objecs.get(quality__in = filt['quality'], presentation__in = filt['presentation'], color__in = filt[''color])
```

But i don't want to make it like this, because if the user didn't set a value for any of the values, then it will be an empty list on the dict, and this will make that the search fails because will want to search the unset atribute with the null, instead of not searching for it.

By the way, the user can set multiple parameters for one variable in the filter, i mean, quality = [1,2].

Comment: You can unpack a dictionary in filter like `Product.objects.filter(**filt)`, but the keys inside the dictionary will need to map to the fields of the object you are applying to filter to. If that makes sense. So if your values are lists, the keys would need to be '{field_name}__in'.

Comment: Yeah, this worked, of course, i was making another mistake using get instead of filter, but apart of that, what you said worked with what i was planing to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer for future readers (probably should have done that to begin with).

To unpack a dictionary into a filter call in Django do the following:

```
Product.objects.filter(**filt)
```

The trick is the fields of the dictionary need to map to the fields of the object. So, if your values are lists, then the following would work:

```
{ "<field_name>__in": [] }
```